# Where does Bower install my packages?

Tags: zurb-foundation, bower

Ok, be forewarned, I am SUPER noob when it comes to bower. I have a very sketchy basic understanding of what it even is and barely know how to do anything on it. So bear with me here. Also, I'm working on Windows here.

I installed node.js, and then used npm to install bower. After spending half my life trying to find the bower folder, if found it in

```
C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower
```

However, I just installed Foundation via Bower and have NO idea where it installed the Foundation files. I assume from my Google searches that it's in the bower_components folder, but I have no idea where that is. I haven't moved it around or done anything abnormal, so I assume it should just be somewhere pretty standard, but I can't find it anywhere! Any pointers on where to look? I have looked this up online a bunch of times, but either this is super obvious so nobody has ever been noob enough to ask it or I'm just bad at Googling my life problems. Is there a command I can run to find out where this is?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you are using `-g` flag when isntalling, it tells `npm` or `bower` to install packages globally. It meens you can use them in the whole system and not only for the one project. In this case they are installed into `AppData` folder, `node_modules` for `npm` and `bower_components` for `bower`.

On the other hand, if you don't use `-g` flag, you are installing packages only for the project which you are actually working on. It is simply the folder where you are when you run the install command. Then folders `node_packages` and `bower_components` are created in your actual folder and packages are placed into them.

Answer (score 0):

If you install with `-g` flag, packages will be install globally. But when you download without -g flag, you can change bower package directory with `.bowerrc` file.

You should create `.bowerrc` file if not exist, and write this in file.

```
{
  "directory" : "src/components"
}
```